# JMeter Behind proxy for load test

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, http-proxy

I have a requirement to do load test on server which runs behind a proxy. We are using shell script for performing load test(16 concurrent calls). 
Please advice if I can port those script to JMeter  to do load test behind proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, check out [Using JMeter behind a proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) chapter of the JMeter User Manual, the options are in:

1. Use `-H` and `-P` command-line arguments like:

   ```
   jmeter -H your_proxy_host -P your_proxy_port -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
2. Use `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort` Java System properties like:

   ```
   jmeter -Dhttp.proxyHost=your_proxy_host -Dhttp.proxyPort=your_proxy_port -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
3. You can make the changes "permanent" by adding the next lines to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   http.proxyHost=your_proxy_host
   http.proxyPort=your_proxy_port
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up

For more information on points 2 and 3 see [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) and [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that your proxy will not become the bottleneck for your testing efforts?  The least scale-able item in the path will govern the perceived performance of your clients.